# Is there an Android implementation of JOGL's GL2ES2?

Tags: android, jogl

JOGL includes several interfaces that represent the common features of various versions of OpenGL and OpenGL-ES.

Is there an Android implementation of the [`GL2ES2`](http://jogamp.org/deployment/jogamp-next/javadoc/jogl/javadoc/com/jogamp/opengl/GL2ES2.html) interface somewhere in one of the JOGL packages, or do I have to bite the bullet and implement it myself?

Comment: hi Kevin, have you already look at [this thread](http://forum.jogamp.org/Steps-to-build-Android-Demo-Application-with-JOGL-td4033491.html)?

Comment: [This](http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Android_Packages) also

Comment: @elect Yes, but I can't find any of the demo sources mentioned there.  For example, where is `jogl-demos/android/JOGLStandaloneGearsES2Test/`?

Comment: Uhm, you are right, I can't find it right now.. I will be back

Comment: You can find some tests for Android here: https://github.com/sgothel/jogl/tree/master/src/test/com/jogamp/opengl/test/android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read this documentation:
http://jogamp.org/jogl/doc/Overview-OpenGL-Evolution-And-JOGL.html

JOGL 2 already works as is under Android. What are you trying to do? Numerous tablets and mobile phones support OpenGL-ES.

Imagine that you want to launch a Java program using JOGL on my Samsung Galaxy S3 4G i9305. It supports both OpenGL ES 1 and OpenGL ES 2, it will pick the former or the latter depending on how you create your GL profile. If it picks OpenGL ES 2, GLContext.getCurrentGL() will return a GLES2 instance. GLES2 is a subinterface of GL2ES2. What's the matter with that?

Comment: I intend to write methods similar to one of the examples given on that page: `renderSomething(GL2ES2 gl) { ... }`.  Could you explain more thoroughly what needs to be done before calling `GLContext.getCurrentGL()`?  I'm struggling to understand your answer because the page you linked does not mention Android at all.  There's [almost nothing](https://www.google.com/search?q=inurl%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fjogamp.org%2Fjogl+android) about Android on the JOGL site.  There are only 13 SO questions (including this one) tagged `jogl` and `android`, and some of the most promising ones contain dead links.

Comment: Try [this search](https://www.google.de/search?q=jogl+android+site:forum.jogamp.org&safe=off&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi7tZiGsrXKAhXJbBoKHSgNBCoQrQIIMygEMAE&biw=1536&bih=731)

Comment: elect is right. This post is helpful: http://forum.jogamp.org/Recreating-Jogl2-Android-demo-projects-in-Eclipse-td4027079.html#a4027138 Stackoverflow isn't the panacea but there is a real lack of documentation for JOGL Android support. You should look at our demos based on ES2: http://jogamp.org/git/?p=jogl.git;a=tree;f=src/test/com/jogamp/opengl/test/junit/jogl/demos/es2;hb=HEAD You shouldn't have to use GLContext.getCurrentGL() if your OpenGL code is in your GLEventListener, only use this method to avoid passing and storing GL instances.

Comment: Using JOGL under Android isn't noticeably different than using JOGL under common desktop operating systems except that you need to create an activity and to use the Android SDK. You can use NEWT both in desktop and in embedded environments. The page I linked mention "mobile", it includes Android. Don't expect a totally different code path for Android. JOGL tries to minimize the efforts to do to write cross-platform environments without preventing you from writing platform-dependent code.

Comment: @gouessej It sounds like the answer is "yes", just not in the way I expected.  JOGL does not use Android's standard GLES bindings, but provides its own, using its own native libraries.  Presumably it also provides its own drawing surface.  Is that correct?

Comment: JOGL uses its own Java binding for the OpenGL ES API but it calls the same native methods than the standard Android OpenGL ES bindings. It doesn't provide its own drawing surface but it provides its own native windowing toolkit (NEWT) that acts as an abstraction of the platform dependent windowing "layers". What did you expect?

Comment: I assumed the ES2 implementation would simply be a thin wrapper around `android.opengl.GLES20`.  Now I'm curious why the library is 3 MB and requires multiple APKs if all it's doing is calling existing native libraries.  I'll read those links and perhaps ask another question.

Comment: I've read everything I can find and I'm still completely baffled about using JOGL on Android.  From the perspective of an experienced Android developer, JOGL makes no sense whatsoever.  I can't even find the entry point to the library.

Comment: Some other experienced Android developers strongly disagree with you as JOGL is used under Android in several commercial softwares including a game and a visualization suite (C3D Interactive). The main advantage of JOGL under Android is the ability to use the same OpenGL rendering code both in desktop and mobile environments but there is a serious lack of tooling and documentation. I totally understand that it's very interesting for developers who would like to port a desktop software to Android but it might be a lot less attractive for the developers only focused on Android.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede, if you are available, we can cooperate and improve tooling and documentation, what do you think? Does it sound interesting for you?

Comment: @elect Sure.  How can I get involved?

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede There are some posts in the forum (including this: http://forum.jogamp.org/Gluegen-apk-won-t-install-on-Android-6-Marshmallow-tp4036114p4036185.html) and some examples for Android but nothing about that in our official wiki: http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page

Comment: I guess we can start by continuing this topic to jogl forums, the thread linked by gouessej seems to be a good place